# A better way to list hosts with a specific set of TCP ports open (Linux)

Tags: linux, networking

I want to get a list of all the hosts in my network that have ports 22, 80 and 443 open (*all three of them*). Currently I'm using two methods, both have drawbacks and I wonder if there is a better way that I'm missing.

**1st Method**:

```
nmap -PS22 -p22,80,443 192.168.2.\* -oG - | grep "open.*open.*open"
Host: 192.168.2.250 (192.168.2.250) Ports: 22/open/tcp//ssh///, 80/open/tcp//http///, 443/open/tcp//https///
```

I need to match the number of ports with the number of appearances of the "open" word. It's ugly, it's long and its output is even longer and uglier

**2nd Method**:

```
nmap -PS22 -p22,80,443 192.168.2.*
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.250 (192.168.2.250)
Host is up (0.051s latency).
22/tcp open  ssh
80/tcp open  http
443/tcp open  https
```

This is a simpler command but it requires that I visually locate the hosts that have 3 lines of open ports like in the example above. In a network with a lot of hosts that have only one or two of the three ports open it's difficult.

Any better way?

Comment: Your first command gives you exactly what you want - surely you just need to format the output to be easy to read? Like by adding ` | cut -f2 -d\ ` to pull out the ip address.

Comment: if it was exactly what I needed I wouldn't be here asking for a  better way :-)

Comment: To explain myself better: surely your addition remedies my complains about the long and ugly output but the command itself is still long and ugly (ugly because one must match the number of ports to the number of `open` words in the regex and that's easy to forget)

Comment: But why do you care what the command looks like?  Once it is in a script, you can make it look as pretty as you like.  If you are using something like this regularly, it isn't something you should ever need to type in or remember.

Comment: And here is your command line once done: `findports 192.168.2.\* 22 80 443`

Comment: I guess that if one is typing commands in a CLI for many years one starts to see elegance and ugliness where none exists. It *is* definitely something highly subjective. Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Both are pretty easy to parse. The second one like this:

```
nmap -PS22 -p22,80,443 192.168.2.* | awk '/^Nmap scan/ { host = $NF; gsub( /[()]/, "", host) }; /^(22|80|443)/ && $2=="open" { open=open " " $3;  ++cnt}; host && /^$/ { printf "%2s %-20s %s\n", (cnt!=3 ? "!" : "OK"), host, open; host=open=""; cnt=0}'
```

This will print an indicator (OK or !) in the 1st column, then the IP, and finally the names of the services it found open.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Very nice example of the power of awk but  I can't see what's *better* in your answer compared to my first method which as I said I find ugly and long